# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception - WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, nlog

So I have a WCF service that i created that gets messages from customer and parses them to desired output and sends them to other customer via TCP/HTTP/FTP etc.
This windows service has long running threads for each customer created using TPL's.

So for logging I have used NLOG, log to file and event viewer with below configurations

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="flatfile" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring,StackTrace}" 
              archiveAboveSize="2000000" archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive/${shortdate}-{#####}.engine.log" archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveEvery="None" 
              maxArchiveFiles="100" fileName="${basedir}/logs/engine.current.log" keepFileOpen="true" concurrentWrites="true" />

<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${StackTrace}" log="Application" source="Nuance Interface Engine Service" eventId="${event-properties:EventID}" />
```

Even when I added concurrentWrites="true", when I start WCF service after 20+ hours of time passes I got below error in event viewer

```
    Application: MyWcfService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.Text.StringBuilder..ctor(System.String, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout.GetFormattedMessage(NLog.LogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.GetFormattedMessage(NLog.LogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.GetBytesToWrite(NLog.LogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo[])
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvents(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo[])
   at NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireQueuedTimerCompletion(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Could you please someone guide me on where this issue is occuring, I thought multiple threads are accessing this log file hence I added concurrentWrites="true" attribute to nlog's file target.

after 1 second passes to above error, I see one more error in my event viewer.

```
Faulting application name: Hl7ic.Engine.View.exe, version: 18.0.1.160, time stamp: 0x5af5cd1f
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18938, time stamp: 0x5a7dd8a7
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00015ef8
Faulting process id: 0x1074
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3ea7338d9851c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyServices\MyWcfService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 59b36929-5688-11e8-80ca-005056a80aaa
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Your answer is in the exception details: "Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException"

Comment: Yea I checked that, but how to fix that issue, because I have not changed NLOG's configuration since project was build 3 yrs back. I just running these in multiple threads.

Comment: You would need to profile your codebase to figure out where you have issue. It will not be possible to answer this question without extensive knowledge about the code base. There are tools that allow to take memory dumps during certain events like debug diagnositcs tools and so on so you could investigate these memory dumps to find potential memory leaks and so on. Could it be that the service is a 32bit process and not a 64bit?

Comment: Yes you are right service is 32bit

Comment: If it is crashing constantly and you are scrambling to fix production issues right now I would probably recompile it is AnyCPU so it can run as a 64bit process. That should at least buy you some time until you figure out where your memory leak is.

Comment: Is this because of Nlog or something else in my code

Comment: That is not possible for me to say. It just happens to throw OOM exception when it tried to write a log message in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryException` means that there is not enough memory on the machine. Maybe it has been used up by another application. Maybe it has been used up by your application. Maybe your 32 bit application have used up its memory address space of 2 Gigabyte.

To diagnose this error, then use Process Explorer to capture a Fulldump of the application that uses too much memory. Then try using Visual Studio or WinDbg to investigate the memory dumpfile.

To remove NLog from the radar, then you can upgrade to NLog 4.4.6 (or newer). It will reduce memory allocations with 70 pct. from older versions (When using FileTarget)

If running NLog 4.4.6 (or newer) then you can optimize NLog even further by not using `<targets async="true">` but instead use this `default-wrapper`:

```xml
<targets>
   <default-wrapper xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" />

   <target .... />

   <target .... />

</targets>
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance

Comment: Hi Rolf, sorry for the delayed response after upgrading NLog version to 4.5.4 memory exception is is not occured, I have ran my service for 30hrs, thanks for your help.
Now new problem is seen, nlog's Event Viewer configuration is dumping almost 80GBs of information within 24hrs, that is very dangerous for my case. Do you have any options for me to archive or compress event viewer logs? help much appreciated.

Comment: <target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${StackTrace}" log="Application" source="Nuance Interface Engine Service" eventId="${event-properties:EventID}" />


<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="eventlog" />

this is the configuration in my app.config

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem with the EventLog-target. Usually there is an upper limit of 64 KByte for a Windows EventLog. So if writing more than 64 KByte then it starts to discard old items. If you are writing more than 80 Gigabyte, then I think you should reconsider that information is relevant for the Windows-EventLog. Maybe increase the Logger-minLevel to `Warn` ? (Again this sounds like a different problem)

Comment: yes you are correct to avoid HDD full I have changed minlevel from Trace to Warn. thanks